# Codeigniter+HMVC+ION_AUTH language file load issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI+HMVC+ION_AUTH on my project, everything works as expected but I  am getting following error when I go to the root of the project.

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/ion_auth_lang.php
```

I searched around but no solutions available. can anyone share some light here please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that mean you are loading the file which is not present... or you have an incorrect path..

make sure you have ion_auth_lang inside >application/language directory

> CodeIgniter will look first in your application/language directory. If the directory does not exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead look in your global system/language folder.

check how you are loading the lang file..

```
 $this->lang->load('ion_auth_lang.php', 'english');
```

go through the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html) to read more

Comment: I just places a empty php file in the application/language/english/ion_auth_lang.php and error was gone, everything else seems to be working propely.

@bipen, thanks for the reply, I feel like my brain has not done it's job properly :).

Comment: welcome... happens sometimes.. :)... anyways glad it helped.. happy coding